# How to Store Values from Controller into Service?

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-repeat list in a partial. From this list(messages), i want to store the clicked item into a Service, I dont just want to store one, i want to store as many as was clicked.

On the otherhand i want to be able to pull that data and place it into the controller i have the service on.

If you see a way to improve my existing code please let me know. i am still learning Angularjs its FUN!

The feature is as similar to:
http://qnimate.com/facebook-style-chat-box-popup-using-javascript-and-css/

Except i do not know how to convert that method into angularjs.

1. User clicks on message
2. Message Appears on Taskbar
3. User can add multiple messages into the taskbar

I have kind of started the Service:

```
app.factory('chatbox',['$http',function($http){

  var chats; << Variable to hold chats array


  return {
      killChat:  function (userid) {

      },
      registerChat: function (userid) {

      }
  };

}]);
```

And the Controller:

```
app.controller("taskbarController", ['$scope', 'authData', '$location', '$aside', 'Poller',
  function ($scope, authData, $location, $aside, Poller) {

    $scope.openChat = function() {
        // function to add message to Service Array
    }

    $scope.getChat = function() {
        // Retrieve Open Chats from Array and display on Taskbar?
        // possible to template the return data into html and then inject where needed?
    }

    $scope.openAside = function(position) {
      $aside.open({
        placement: position,
        templateUrl: 'partials/sidemenu.html',
        size: 'sm'
        });
    };

    $scope.logout = function () {
        authData.get('logout').then(function (results) {
            authData.toast(results);
            $location.path('login');
        });
    }

    authData.get('session');

}]);
```

Comment: Would it be best to $http the messages from database or can i just pass them into the array? what is more efficient?

Comment: This syntax `var chats {[  ]};` is not correct JS.

Comment: @ShaojiangCai ah yes thanks for that i didnt realise it.